# When should I use な in "na-adjectives"?

Tags: adjectives, na-adjectives

I'm trying to understand something here, I have the following question I need to answer:

> あなたの部屋はきれいですか？

to which I should answer something like

> ええ、きれい**な**です。

Why is the question does not contain the な?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, your question is right and your answer is wrong.

You will only use な after a "na-adjective" if you're modifying a noun/adjective with it, for instance:

> あなたの部屋はきれいですか (anata no heya wa kirei desu ka) Is your room beautiful?
>
> はい、きれいですよ (hai, kirei desu yo) Yep, it is beautiful.

**きれい is not modifying any noun, therefore there's no need for using な in this.**

But if you wanted, you could word your answer like this:

> はい、きれいな部屋ですよ！ (hai, kirei na heya desu yo!) Yep, it's a beautiful room!

here we wanna state clearly that it is the room that has the quality of being beautiful, in order to do that we, then, need to attach な after the adjective, therefore:

**きれいな部屋 (na-adjective + na + noun)**

Comment: I am starting to think that な-particle for adjectives is the special case of the の-particle which is usung for nouns.

Comment: It is simmilar in function in a way that it sort of connects the na-adjective to the word, the same way the の particle connects two words. But  maybe if you think about it too much, you'll be confused when you start seeing explanatory sentences with なのです  -> https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60454/what-does-9%e6%9c%88%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8b10%e6%9c%88%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%82%88-mean/60456#60456