# What does 9月とか10月なんですよ mean?

Tags: meaning, words, sentence

What does 9月とか10月なんですよ mean?

> 日本で台風と言うと
>   9月とか10月なんですよ
>   7月に上陸とか聞いたことありません

We were chatting about typhoons. Does it mean "What? We still have September and October, you know"?  In particular, I want to know what the "なんですよ" means.

Comment: Funny 'cause I personally seem typhoons in japan in august though

Comment: Don't confuse this 'なんです' with the interrogative version. The one in your sentence means roughly 'it's that...' and is used for giving a reason or context - nothing to do with asking 'what'. There are effectively three parts to it; first is な which in this context is not dissimilar to the な used in な-adjectives. Next is ん which is a short version of の; this の is a variable particle which 'contains' everything before it. Finally, です which I doubt needs explaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The とか used here is a way of listing, it's somewhat the informal counterpart of や, which means that it is a listing that goes on "1, 2, 3..."

So let's breakdown this chat:

> 日本で台風と言うと - When it comes to Typhoon.
>
> 9月とか10月なんですよ - It is September, October...
>
> 7月に上陸とか聞いたことありません - I haven't heard of typhoons happening in July.

Therefore:

> When it comes to Typhoons, they usually happen in September, October... I have never heard of Typhoons in July.

Another quick example where I use とか a lot:

> Japanese Person: 日本のどこへ行ったの？Where did you go in Japan.
>
> Foreigner: 東京とか、京都とか、大阪に行ったよ。　I went to Tokyo, Kyoto, Osaka, etc.

Edit: **"I wanted to know what the nan desuyo meant."**:

なんですよ is the contraction of なのですよ。
Basically, since this person is exaplaining to you something about Typhoons, he/she is adding the の particle, to add more emphasis to the explanation.

Now, since 月 is a noun, you gotta add the な before it. Therefore, 月なのですよ。